# Catching a variable for later use in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am relatively new to Ruby, but I am trying to catch a variable for later use.

Example:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
y.reverse!
```

How do I get the original value of x back?  It looks like x got changed when I changed y.  Basically I need to catch and hold a variable value while altering a copy of it.
Many thanks!
AlanR

Comment: Do you *really* need to dup it? I don't know the larger context of your program, but I rarely need to dup variables. If you use the return values of expressions and methods wisely, you can avoid too much intermediate variable creation.

Comment: Do you mean caching, not catching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.dup` to create a clone of x.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x.dup
y
```

Answer (score 6):

A number of "mutating!" methods are paired with an equivalent non-mutating form. (Generally, if such a pair exists, the non-mutating form lacks the trailing `!` in the name.)

In this case, and in every case *unless there is a good reason to justify otherwise*, I recommend using the non-mutating form. I find that reducing side-effects makes code cleaner and also reduces subtle little issues like this. (`gsub!` can be particularly icky.)

```
>> x = [1,2,3]                                                          
=> [1, 2, 3]                                                            
>> y = x                                                                
=> [1, 2, 3]                                                            
>> y = y.reverse                                                            
=> [3, 2, 1]                                                            
>> x                                                                    
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst), it's bad style to mutate the original object rather than using a functional expression to create a new and modified version.

```
y = x.reverse # problem solved
```